# GET or PUT to reboot a remote resource?

Tags: api, http, rest, get, put

I am struggling (in some sense) to determine which HTTP method is more appropriate for rebooting a remote resource: GET or PUT?

On one hand, it seems more semantic to call `http://tools.serviceprovider.net/canopies/d34db33fc4f3?reboot=true` because one might want to GET a representation of a freshly rebooted canopy.

On the other hand, a reboot is not 'safe' (nor is it necessarily idempotent, but then a canopy or modem is not just a row in a database) so it might seem more semantic to PUT the canopy into a state of rebooting, then have the server return a 202 to indicate that the reboot was initiated and is processing.

I have been reading up on HTTP/1.1, REST, HATEOAS, and other related concepts over the last week, so I am still putting the pieces together. Could a more seasoned developer please weigh in and confirm or dispel my hunch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GET doesn't seem appropriate because a GET is expected, like you said, to be "safe". i.e. no action other than retrieval.

A PUT doesn't seem appropriate because a PUT is expected to be idempotent. i.e. multiple identical operations cause same side-effects as as a single operation. Moreover, a PUT is usually used to *replace* the content at the request URI with the request body.

A POST appears most appropriate here. Because:

1. A POST need not be safe
2. A POST need not be idempotent

It also appears meaningful in that you are POSTing a request for a reboot (much like submitting a form, which also happens via POST), which can then be processed, possibly leading to a new URI containing reboot logs/results returned along with a `303 See Other` status code.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it makes sense -- POST is not idempotent and a reboot is not idempotent and it is like POSTing a new reboot request, like you have said. Semantic and matching the HTTP spec it seems.

I also really like the 303 to reboot log idea; maybe I will use that for CMTSes or APs or other major equipment that have more impact when rebooted. For a modem or canopy a 202 should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, Tim Bray wrote a [blog post](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2009/03/20/Rest-Casuistry) on this exact topic (which method to use to tell a resource representing a virtual machine to reboot itself), in which he also argued for POST.  At the bottom of that post there are links to follow-ups on that topic, including one from none other than Roy Fielding himself, who concurs.

Comment: Thanks for the reading. It does seem that on a resource that sort of has its own 'API' or remote procedure calls that you should post commands to it. It would be RESTful to include some instructions about POSTing the commands to the resource as well, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Rest is definitely not HTTP. But HTTP definitely does not have only four (or eight) methods. Any method is technically valid (even if as an extension method) and any method is RESTful when it is *self describing* — such as ‘LOCK’, ‘REBOOT’, ‘DELETE’, etc. Something like ‘MUSHROOM’, while valid as an HTTP extension, has no clear meaning or easily anticipated behavior, thus it would not be RESTful.

Fielding has stated that “The REST style doesn’t suggest that limiting the set of methods is a desirable goal. [..] In particular, REST encourages the creation of new methods for obscure operations” and that “it is more efficient in a true REST-based architecture for there to be a hundred different methods with distinct (non-duplicating), universal semantics.”

Sources:

http://xent.com/pipermail/fork/2001-August/003191.html

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/4732

With this all in mind I am going to be 'self descriptive' and use the REBOOT method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could effectively create a new command, REBOOT, using POST.  But there is a [perfectly idempotent way to do reboots using PUT](http://nicholassterling.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/rebootrestart-in-a-rest-api-using-put/).

Have a last_reboot field that contains the time at which the server was last rebooted.  Make a PUT to that field with the current time cause a reboot if the incoming time is newer than the current time. If an intermediate server resends the PUT, no problem -- it has the same value as the first command, so it's a no-op.

You might want to get the current time from the server you're rebooting, unless you know that everyone is reasonably time-synced.

Or you could just use a times_rebooted count, eliminating the need for a clock.  A `PUT times_rebooted: 4` request will cause a reboot if times_rebooted is currently 3, but not if it's 4 or 5.  If the current value is 2 and you PUT a 4, that's an error.

The only advantage to using time, if you have a clock, is that sometimes you care about when it happened.  You could of course have BOTH a times_rebooted and a last_reboot_time, letting times_rebooted be the trigger.

Comment: to replace last_reboot_time by last_reboot_uptime is authorized ? is it idempotent ?
If I do PUT uptime = 0... device should reboot, isn't ? (and it is RESTful ?)

Comment: @ipStack What you describe wouldn't be idempotent; if the message got repeated, you'd reboot twice.  You want to PUT last_reboot_time: <some representation of the current time> and have the server check that against the current value.  If it's AFTER the current value, then it needs to save that as the new value and reboot.

Comment: And it is good If I do "PUT rebooting = true" ?... I'm not sure to understand the word idempotent.
If I send  "PUT rebooting = true" twice, result will be the same : device will reboot after some secondes.
But if I re-send "PUT rebooting = true" after the reboot, device will be reboot... is it idempotent ?

Comment: Problem with your example is the device must have an internal clock : with embedded system, this is not always the case...and Idon't understand why your methode is idempotent : the first time that you send the command, device reboots... but the second time (after reboot), it doesn't reboot... result isn't the same. An idempotent command, isn't it supposed to make the same result?

Comment: If you don't have a clock, you can just use a count.
PUT times_rebooted: 1 will reboot if times_rebooted is 0, but not if it's already 1.  I'll change the answer to mention this.

Comment: You might want to check the definition of idempotent.  If an idempotent command is repeated, it will only be executed once.  The network could deliver multiple copies of a reboot PUT request, but you only want to reboot once.